# More expressions in for statement xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to include more statements in the for statement. Now I do this:

```
for (UIImageView* img in imageArray){
for (UITextField* txt in messagename){

}}
```

...but in this way it repeats the code more than once, so I tried this:

```
for (UIImageView* img in imageArray)||(UITextField* txt in messagename)
```

but it does not work!!

EDIT:

```
for (UIImageView* img in imageArray)||(UITextField* txt in messagename) {


    img.hidden = YES;

    CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    [anim setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
    [anim setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI/80]]; // rotation angle
    [anim setDuration:0.1];
    [anim setRepeatCount:NSUIntegerMax];
    [anim setAutoreverses:YES];
    //[img.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"iconShake"];


    UIImage *tmpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"message small type 2.png"];
    CGRect cellRectangle;
    cellRectangle = CGRectMake(20, img.frame.origin.y + 45, 710, 60);
    UIImageView *dragger = [[Draggable alloc] initWithFrame:cellRectangle];
    [dragger setImage:tmpImage];
    [dragger setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:dragger];

    [wobbleImage addObject: dragger];

    Draggable* sharedSingleton = [Draggable sharedManagerDraggable];
    sharedSingleton.namePassedToDraggable = txt.text;

    dragger.tag = img.tag;

    dragger.layer.cornerRadius = 10; // this value vary as per your desire
    dragger.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [dragger.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"iconShake"];

}
```

Comment: Will both arrays always have the same number of objects? If not, then you need to explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: rmaddy is right, we need more context of your problem

Comment: the arrays always have the same number of objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both arrays will alway have the same number of objects, then what you probably want is:

```
NSUInteger count = imageArray.count;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    UIImageView *img = imageArray[i];
    UITextField *txt = messagename[i];

    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: well a bit faster than me ;D